# Three.js + CSS3DRenderer.js => How to get Matrix 3D Values on change?

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

CSS3DRenderer.js creates a 3D element (named matrix3d). When the view changes - the matrix3d elements changes as well. It creates a div (line 66) that outputs in the div style the following values:

```
style="transform-style: preserve-3d; width: 460px; height: 738px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 480.89px) matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1) translate3d(230px, 369px, 0px);"
```

I need to create a new JS file that loads on the page (after Three.js and CSS3DRenderer.js) that will listen to those values, so I would be able to create an If statement and manage events based on changes in the matrix3d values.

- *Please let me know how could this be done.*

This is the CSS3DRenderer.js code (no need to go over all of it, just around line 66.):

```
THREE.CSS3DObject = function ( element ) {

        THREE.Object3D.call( this );

        this.element = element;
        this.element.style.position = 'absolute';

        this.addEventListener( 'removed', function ( event ) {

            if ( this.element.parentNode !== null ) {

                this.element.parentNode.removeChild( this.element );

                for ( var i = 0, l = this.children.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

                    this.children[ i ].dispatchEvent( event );

                }

            }

        } );

    };

    THREE.CSS3DObject.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Object3D.prototype );

    THREE.CSS3DSprite = function ( element ) {

        THREE.CSS3DObject.call( this, element );

    };

    THREE.CSS3DSprite.prototype = Object.create( THREE.CSS3DObject.prototype );

    //

    THREE.CSS3DRenderer = function () {

        /!*console.log( 'THREE.CSS3DRenderer', THREE.REVISION );*!/

        var _width, _height;
        var _widthHalf, _heightHalf;

        var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

        var domElement = document.createElement( 'div' );
        domElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';

        domElement.style.WebkitTransformStyle = 'preserve-3d';
        domElement.style.MozTransformStyle = 'preserve-3d';
        domElement.style.oTransformStyle = 'preserve-3d';
        domElement.style.transformStyle = 'preserve-3d';

        this.domElement = domElement;

        var cameraElement = document.createElement( 'div');
        cameraElement.className += 'resting';

        cameraElement.style.WebkitTransformStyle = 'preserve-3d';
        cameraElement.style.MozTransformStyle = 'preserve-3d';
        cameraElement.style.oTransformStyle = 'preserve-3d';
        cameraElement.style.transformStyle = 'preserve-3d';

        domElement.appendChild( cameraElement );

        this.setClearColor = function () {

        };

        this.setSize = function ( width, height ) {

            _width = width;
            _height = height;

            _widthHalf = _width / 2;
            _heightHalf = _height / 2;

            domElement.style.width = width + 'px';
            domElement.style.height = height + 'px';

            cameraElement.style.width = width + 'px';
            cameraElement.style.height = height + 'px';

        };

        var epsilon = function ( value ) {

            return Math.abs( value ) < 0.000001 ? 0 : value;

        };

        var getCameraCSSMatrix = function ( matrix ) {

            var elements = matrix.elements;

            return 'matrix3d(' +
                epsilon( elements[ 0 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( - elements[ 1 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 2 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 3 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 4 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( - elements[ 5 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 6 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 7 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 8 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( - elements[ 9 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 10 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 11 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 12 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( - elements[ 13 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 14 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 15 ] ) +
            ')';

        };

        var getObjectCSSMatrix = function ( matrix ) {

            var elements = matrix.elements;

            return 'translate3d(-50%,-50%,0) matrix3d(' +
                epsilon( elements[ 0 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 1 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 2 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 3 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( - elements[ 4 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( - elements[ 5 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( - elements[ 6 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( - elements[ 7 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 8 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 9 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 10 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 11 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 12 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 13 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 14 ] ) + ',' +
                epsilon( elements[ 15 ] ) +
            ')';

        };

        var renderObject = function ( object, camera ) {

            if ( object instanceof THREE.CSS3DObject ) {

                var style;

                if ( object instanceof THREE.CSS3DSprite ) {

                    // http://swiftcoder.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/constructing-a-billboard-matrix/

                    matrix.copy( camera.matrixWorldInverse );
                    matrix.transpose();
                    matrix.copyPosition( object.matrixWorld );
                    matrix.scale( object.scale );

                    matrix.elements[ 3 ] = 0;
                    matrix.elements[ 7 ] = 0;
                    matrix.elements[ 11 ] = 0;
                    matrix.elements[ 15 ] = 1;

                    style = getObjectCSSMatrix( matrix );

                } else {

                    style = getObjectCSSMatrix( object.matrixWorld );

                }

                var element = object.element;

                element.style.WebkitTransform = style;
                element.style.MozTransform = style;
                element.style.oTransform = style;
                element.style.transform = style;

                if ( element.parentNode !== cameraElement ) {

                    cameraElement.appendChild( element );

                }

            }

            for ( var i = 0, l = object.children.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

                renderObject( object.children[ i ], camera );

            }

        };

        this.render = function ( scene, camera ) {

            var fov = 0.5 / Math.tan( THREE.Math.degToRad( camera.fov * 0.5 ) ) * _height;

            domElement.style.WebkitPerspective = fov + "px";
            domElement.style.MozPerspective = fov + "px";
            domElement.style.oPerspective = fov + "px";
            domElement.style.perspective = fov + "px";

            scene.updateMatrixWorld();

            if ( camera.parent === undefined ) camera.updateMatrixWorld();

            camera.matrixWorldInverse.getInverse( camera.matrixWorld );

            var style = "translate3d(0,0," + fov + "px)" + getCameraCSSMatrix( camera.matrixWorldInverse ) +
                " translate3d(" + _widthHalf + "px," + _heightHalf + "px, 0)";

            cameraElement.style.WebkitTransform = style;
            cameraElement.style.MozTransform = style;
            cameraElement.style.oTransform = style;
            cameraElement.style.transform = style;

            renderObject( scene, camera );

        };

    };
```

Comment: After `cache.camera.style = style;` add `console.log( fov, camera.matrixWorldInverse );`. Then replace `console.log` with your function.

Comment: @WestLangley - but I don't want to replace anything in the CSS3DRenderer file. I just want to extract the values, and not only on page load, but on any given time. Please read the question mate, or maybe I didnt understand you?

Comment: Perhaps someone else can help you, then.